# Does P(A|B) = P(A) and P(B|A) = P(B) imply independence?

Tags: statistics

I was going through KhanAcademy's practice questions and came across this question:

> 150 students in a tenth grade high school class take a survey about
> which video game consoles they own. 60 students answer that one of
> their consoles is a Playstation, 50 answer that one of their
> consoles is an Xbox. Out of these, there are 20 who have both
> systems.

> Let A be the event that a randomly selected student in the
> class has a Playstation and B be the event that the student has an
> XBOX.

> Is P(A|B) = P(A)? Are the events A and B independent?

Using the given values, P(A|B) = P(A) as P(A|B) = 20/50 = 2/5, and P(A) = 60/150 = 2/5, so they are equal. Does this imply they are independent though? If I change the number of students that have Playstation to 50 (all else remaining the same), P(A|B) = 2/5 but P(A) = 1/3, they are not equal. If these are truly independent events, shouldn't the original relationship hold up regardless of what the values are?

Comment: Given P(A|B) = P(A), therefore P(A, B)  = P(A|B) P(B) (definition of joint probability) = P(A) P(B) (by hypothesis), i.e. P(A, B) = P(A) P(B) which is to say A and B are independent. Note that if P(A|B) = P(A), then P(B|A) = P(A, B) / P(A) (defn joint probability again) = P(A) P(B) / P(A) (independence as shown before) = P(B), i.e. P(A|B) = P(A) implies P(B|A) = P(B). By the way, this is an interesting, fundamental question, but really suitable for stats.stackexchange.com or math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Robert! I wasn't aware that there's an independent stats.stackexchange.com I will follow up on that board regarding the fundamental relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! If Pr(A|B) = Pr(A), this shows that the outcome of B has no bearing on the probability of A. Therefore, the two events are independent.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of independent events requires that

`P(A B) = P(A) . P(B) [equation 1]`

In this case, we have

`P(A|B) = P(A)  [equation 2]`

By definition,

`P(A|B) = P(A B) / P(B)  [equation 3]`

Combinig equations 2 and 3, we obtain

```
P(A B) / P(B) = P(A) =>
P(A B) = P(A) . P(B)
```

Which is equation 1. So the answer is `P(A|B) = P(A)` implies independence.

Notice that only one of `P(A|B) = P(A)` or `P(B|A) = P(B)` is necessary, because what has been shown is that `P(A|B) = P(A) <=> P(B|A) = P(B) <=> P(A B) = P(A) . P(B)`.

Also notice that changing the number of students changes the probabilities, so the answer to your second question is that no, the original relationship does not hold for any value of probability. The values of the probability are what define the events to be independent.